# How to alter my regex so that preg_match returns the desired string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the string:

```
<mml:mi>P</mml:mi><mml:mn>2</mml:mn>
```

and wish to retrieve the 2

My pattern is:

```
/(?:<mml:)(mn|mi|mo)>(.+)(?:<\/mml:\1>)$/
```

the return is the 2 as it should be,

but if the string is:

```
<mml:mi>P</mml:mi><mml:mi>s</mml:mi>
```

the pattern should then return the s, from inside the second set of tags, but returns the P from inside the first set

```
P</mml:mi><mml:mi>s
```

when changing the pattern as in the suggestion below to:

```
/<mml:(mn|mi|mo)>(.*?)<\/mml:\1>/sU
```

the return is the same. The line of php is:

```
preg_match('/<mml:(mn|mi|mo)>(.*?)<\/mml:\1>/sU', '<mml:mi>P</mml:mi><mml:mi>s</mml:mi>', $ret, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

and $ret contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <mml:mi>P</mml:mi><mml:mi>s</mml:mi>
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => mi
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => P</mml:mi><mml:mi>s
            [1] => 8
        )

)
```

and when changed to the edited suggestion, with the ? removed

```
/<mml:(mn|mi|mo)>(.*)<\/mml:\1>/sU
```

the return is P, from the first occurrence, rather than the s from the second.

Comment: Use [`/<mml:(mn|mi|mo)>(.*)<\/mml:\1>/sU`](https://regex101.com/r/7T5jE1/1)

Comment: Same result. I've added the details to the description.

Comment: You used another regex. Use the regex from my comment.

Comment: I used the regex as it was when I looked, before the edit :-)  The results are closer, but the wrong occurrence, noted in the description.

Comment: To get `s`, you need to [get the second match](https://regex101.com/r/wm8pp2/1). If you need to get the last occurrence, you need to greedily match all at the start [`/.*<mml:(mn|mi|mo)>(.*?)<\/mml:\1>/s`](https://regex101.com/r/wm8pp2/2).

Comment: this looks like xml. You could consider using using php's xml-functions.
Second: how much can  your input string differ? Are both elements, and only those 2 (apart from the 3 namespaces)? And what can de value in the elements look like? (one character, mulitple etc)

Comment: Ivo, just to say, I'm using simplexml but it does not like tags such as mml:mn let alone their attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing from my phone, so will be brief.

Instead of matching any character (.+), match any character that is *not* the beginning of the next tag ([^<]+)

This way you don't have to worry about using back references, nor will you grab everything between two identical tags.

(Double check where I put the caret, this is off the top of my head. )

To get the last occurrence, wrap the whole regex in ()+

```
/(<mml:(mn|mi|mo)>([^<]+)<\/mml:\2>)+/
```

Comment: I was going to select Wiktor's response in favor of this one, but looking more closely at the one, if I add a U after the final escape and use preg_match_all I can have all occurrences of the character within the tags returned. So, while both responses work well, this one provides me some additional benefit if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized pattern, which will not only run faster than Tim's, `preg_match()` will return less elements in the output array:

```
~<m{2}l:(m[ino])>\K[^<](?=</m{2}l:\1>$)~
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dc8Mt4/1)

Enhancements:

1. Replace standard pattern delimiter slash `/` with `~` to avoid escaping for improved brevity.
2. Use quantifiers for consecutive characters for improved efficiency. `{2}`
3. Use character class instead of pipes for improved efficiency and brevity. `m[ino]`
4. Use `\K` to start the fullstring match from middle of pattern, effectively removing the need for an extra capture group for improved efficiency.
5. Use negated character class to match desired character `[^<]` *note, if your desired substring is more than one character use: `[^<]+`
6. Use positive lookahead to accurately match closing tag followed by end of line anchor `$`.

PHP Implementation: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cd66837fa022f6b56d95206645c37028ee75d6d6))

```
echo preg_match('~<m{2}l:(m[ino])>\K[^<](?=</m{2}l:\1>$)~','<mml:mi>P</mml:mi><mml:mi>s</mml:mi>',$out)?$out[0]:'fail';
```

Output:

```
s
```